# angular v11 + Scss failed to compile

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, angular11

We have an existing angular project with `scss` setup architecture like [this](https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/angular11) but after upgrading to angular v11 with angular cli v11, we are facing this issue, not able to find what is causing it [image: this]

can someone help us?

I have also created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jpthpu?file=src/app/app.component.scss) as well.

Thank you in advance.

```
Error: ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\VNelapati\Projects\NXT_Gen\app.component.scss:11:4: Can't resolve './assets/iconscaret-down-blue-16.png' in 'C:\Users\VNelapati\Projects\NXT_Gen\ax-upgrade\angular11\src\app'

   9 |     right: 16px;
  10 |     cursor: pointer;
> 11 |     background-image: url($icon-url +"caret-down-blue-16.png");
     |    ^
  12 | }
  13 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **cloned your repo** instead of your stackblitz since there are instances that Stackblitz doesn't recognize absolute paths on `scss imports`

Have found the problem and In order to resolve your issue:

**1.) Put `/` at the `start` and `end` of your `$icon-url` on your `_variables.scss`:**

```
$icon-url: "/assets/icons/";
```

**2.) On your `app.component.scss`**

> remove `@import "../style/app.scss";` since this is quite redundant as `variables` is already imported on your `standards` scss file. Just have it like this:

```
@import "standards";


body {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 16px;
    right: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url($icon-url +"caret-down-blue-16.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your url. Based on your stakckbliz, you have an `icons` folder inside `assets` but the error tells you it is trying to access `./assets/iconscaret-down-blue-16.png`. You want `./assets/icons/caret-down-blue-16.png`, so add the slash to either `$icon-url` or append it before `caret-down-blue-16.png`. The first option is better if you have several icons, so you do the global fix

Comment: Thanks for answering @PMO1948. I tried both ways but the same error is coming. I have updated the stackblitz too
https://imgur.com/a/mluKvdZ

Comment: at a second look at the error - it is looking for the assets folder in `src/app` as opposed to just `src`. The issue still seems to be with your path - maybe try an absolute path or adding a slash before `assets`?

Comment: Trying @PMO1948